# Are you an amateur(ish) fellow?

Tags: word-choice

A dull, static *power-point presentation* projected its **amateur/amateurish** slides that could descend a brisk subject into an impenetrable bulk of banality.

Both sound correct to me with a bias on the former.

Comment: I prefer the latter (for the reason pointed out by Malvolio), and while descent is a verb, it is not an active one.  You cannot descend something.  Replace it with something like "plunge".

Comment: IMO, it's kind of crappy English... :))

Comment: @EricHauenstein -- you mean to say "descend" is a *intransitive* verb, it does not take an indirect object.  In fact, you can, for example, descend a staircase, but the thing descending is you.

Answer (score 4):

*Amateur* means done by someone who is in fact not a professional in the field.

*Amateurish* means so poorly done as to suggest that it was done by someone who was not a professional in the field.

A professional can be accused of doing amateurish work; accusing him of doing amateur work is a contradiction in terms.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't objecting to the slides because they were produced by someone who did it because they loved doing doing it (amateur), but because they were poorly done (amateurish).

You aren't likely to be called out for using the wrong word, as it's a common error, but you will have the satisfaction of doing it right.

Answer (score 0):

"Amateur" is a noun. "Amateurish" is an adjective. You want the latter to modify "slides."

And these slides could *reduce* "a brisk subject into an impenetrable bulk of banality."

Comment: Tom, what, formally, is the name for a noun which seems to act like an adjective?

Comment: Amateur commonly acts as a noun modifier 'amateur golfer', 'amateur athletics' etc.